# SAP UI5 with ASP: Repeater Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sapui5

Does anyone know how to use an sap ui5 control with the asp:repeater control.  Everytime I try to put a button, it only shows up in the first iteration of the repeater.  And not in the rest of the iterations

```
<asp:Repeater ID="NewsFeedID" runat="server" >
<ItemTemplate>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var buttonlink = CommentsPage + "?news=" + '<%# Eval("NewsFeedID") %>';
                    var AddComment = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                        text: "Add Comment",
                        icon: AddCommentIcon,
                        lite: true,
                        press: function () { window.location = buttonlink;  }
                    }).placeAt("Comments");

                </script>
                <div id="Comments"></div>
            </td>
    </tr>
```

When I use this code it only shows up for the first iteration of the asp:repeater but I want it to show up for all iterations.  Does it have something to do with the div id=Comments?  Need help please

Answer (score 1):

Your Repeater creates multiple `<div>` elements with the same `id`, which causes conflicts.

One way to fix the problem is to add a `runat="server"` attribute to the `<div>`, making it a server-side control so that ASP.NET generates a unique ID for each instance:

```
<div runat="server" id="Comments"></div>
```

Then pass the dynamically generated ID to the `placeAt` function:

```
}).placeAt("<%# Container.FindControl("Comments").ClientID %>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename every instance with the index of repeater item:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var buttonlink = CommentsPage + "?news=" + '<%# Eval("NewsFeedID") %>';
                var AddComment = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                    text: "Add Comment",
                    icon: AddCommentIcon,
                    lite: true,
                    press: function () { window.location = buttonlink;  }
                }).placeAt("<%# "Comments"+ Container.ItemIndex+1 %>");

            </script>
            <div id="<%# "Comments"+ Container.ItemIndex+1 %>"></div>
```